# How to convert openssl_pkey_get_public and openssl_verify to C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cryptography, openssl

PHP code verifies iPizza signature from bank:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_public (file_get_contents ($preferences['bank_certificate'])); 
if (!openssl_verify ($data, $signature, $key)) { 
    trigger_error ("Invalid signature", E_USER_ERROR); 
    }
```

I tried to convert it to ASP .NET using

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/bankert.crt"), "");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoIPT = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaCryptoIPT.ImportCspBlob(cert.RawData);
if (!rsaCryptoIPT.VerifyData(data, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid signature from bank ");
```

but line rsaCryptoIPT.ImportCspBlob(cert.RawData) causes Cryptography.CryptographicException  invalid provider version:

```
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob, SafeProvHandle hProv, CspProviderFlags flags, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.ImportCspBlobHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, Byte[] keyBlob, Boolean publicOnly, CspParameters& parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob)
...
```

How to fix ?

bank_certificate file contains

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDRTCCAq6gAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADB7MQswCQYDVQQGEwJFRTEO
>   ....
>   C82uR/wUZJDw9kj+R1O46/byG8yA+S9FVw==
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

**UPDATE**: I changed code according to tyranid answer to

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/banksert.crt"), "");
var rsaCryptoIPT = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
if (!rsaCryptoIPT.VerifyData(data, sha1, signature))
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid signature from bank ");
```

This code causes Invalid signature from bank exception. Inspecting cert object in shows cert data.
How to fix this so that signature is validated?
Debugger shows that bank cert valid date has expired. Maybe this causes error or VerifyDate second parameter is wrong.

I can successfully sign the data and bank accepts signature using code

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/P12File.p12"), "");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoIPT = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
byte[] binSignature = rsaCryptoIPT.SignData(binData, sha1);
```

Verifying bank signature should be reverse to this process, same algorithms are used. How to verify signature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Enhanced crypto provider installed?
Actually, to not depend on crypto providers, you can use other libraries, which implements all the cryptography stuff in native code. I know about EldoS SecureBlackbox (which is commercial), and Bouncy Castle (free one), however there can be other libraries on market.

Comment: I have standard Windows Vista and this code should be runnning in mono also. I updated code in question to remove crypto provider usage. Now VerifyData returns false. I provided also code which was used to successfully sign data to bank in same computer. I'm expecting that verifying bank signature is somewhat reverse to this. Can be done in .NET 3.5 without additional libraries or which free library (OpenSSL .net wrapper or Bouncy Castle) should used ?

Answer (score 1):

If the X509Certificate2 has successfully imported the cert file then you get the public key of the cert from the PublicKey.Key parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated code in question according to your answer. Now VerifyData returns false. I also provided code which was used to sign data sent to bank. Signature created using this code was accepted by bank. Verifying bank singature should be reverse to this, same signing method is used. How to fix this ?