# Openssl - verify function alternative for c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, verification, ecdsa

Exist any alternative to:

```
$verified = openssl_verify($stringToVerify, pack("H*", $signature), $publicKey, "sha256");
```

...for c# ?

I tried to use class ECDsaCng, but I don't know, how to set public key. I tried download managedOpenSsl from [gitHub](https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net), but I don't know, what to use (I m not good at encryption generally).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert openssl_pkey_get_public and openssl_verify to C# .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238244/how-to-convert-openssl-pkey-get-public-and-openssl-verify-to-c-sharp-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert openssl\_pkey\_get\_public and openssl\_verify to C# .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238244/how-to-convert-openssl-pkey-get-public-and-openssl-verify-to-c-sharp-net)

Comment: The dupe seems to use a certificate, not a public key. Tiny difference; user1897730 what do you require: public key or cert? And what have you already tried?